# How to print the vertical and horizontal line of a matrix by given positions in Java?

Tags: java, loops, multidimensional-array, position

For example we have the matrix:

```
a b j d e f g k
l m a o p y e s
o k v h e l l o
t h a n k s a m
```

And I have a give position: row[2] col[2] for character v. I want to print the horizontal and vertical lines based on that or any other position I get.

My horizontal line for that specific position should be:

```
o k q h e l l o
```

And my vertical line:

```
j a v a
```

Comment: If you consider `a[i,j]` as your selected item, then all verticals will have the same `i` and all horizontals the same `j`. So use two `for` loops and you will have your result.

Comment: Do you know how to iterate over a 2D array in Java? I suggest doing some research. And then think about *what condition needs to hold true to print only a specific row or column of a 2D array*?

Comment: @sleepToke No I don't fully know how to iterate. That's why I solved several 2D array tasks and I am still practicing. If I knew the current answer to that question I wouldn't post it, right?

Comment: Well you are supposed to research the topic and make an effort to solve it yourself before asking a question instead of require from us to do your homework.

Comment: Maybe the following might be of some help on how to ask questions, [homework questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions), [research effort](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users), [Ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Good luck

Answer (score 0):

All you need is 2 for loops but I highly suggest doing some more research into 2-Dimensional arrays

```java
int row_len = 8;//number of elements per row
int num_cols =4;

//print row
for(int i = 0; i<row_len;i++)
   System.out.printf(arr[2][i]);//prints okvhello

System.out.println();

for(int i = 0; i<num_cols;i++)
   System.out.printf(arr[i][2]);//prints java
```

Answer (score 0):

The "trickiest" thing here is really just accounting for the formatting you want.

As we iterate through the array, for some column, we just need to make sure `i` or `j` are equal to our row or column. For example - since `i` corresponds to the first element of elements in our 2D array:

> {"a", "b", "j", "d", "e", "f", "g", "k"}

then we know that **`i` must equal 0 for all of these elements**. Thus we can conclude that to print some row, we just need to make sure `i` is eqaul to the row number we want. We can apply similar logic to grab our column.

```
public class Test {
    private String[][] data = {{"a", "b", "j", "d", "e", "f", "g", "k"}, // i == 0
                               {"l", "m", "a", "o", "p", "y", "e", "s"}, // i == 1
                               {"o", "k", "v", "h", "e", "l", "l", "o"}, // i == 2
                               {"t", "h", "a", "n", "k", "s", "a", "m"}}; // i == 3
                         // j == 0    1    2    3    4    5    6    7

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Test();
    }

    /**
     * Test each of our methods.
     */
    public Test() {
        // GET THE 3RD (POSITION 2) ROW
        System.out.println(getRow(data, 2));

        // GET THE 6TH (POSITION 5) COLUMN
        System.out.println(getCol(data, 5));
    }

    /**
     * Get some row of some 2D array. This method does not check that
     * the row is within the bounds of the 2D array.
     * 
     * @param data
     * @param row
     * @return
     */
    private String getRow(String[][] data, int row) {
        String s = "";

        int numRows = data.length;
        int numCols = data[0].length;

        for (int i = 0; i < numRows; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < numCols; j++) {
                if (i == row) {
                    s += data[i][j];
                    if (i < (numRows - 1)) s += " ";
                }
            }
        }

        return s;
    }

    /**
     * Get some column of some 2D array. This method does not check that
     * the column is within the bounds of the 2D array.
     * 
     * @param data
     * @param col
     * @return
     */
    private String getCol(String[][] data, int col) {
        String s = "";

        int numRows = data.length;
        int numCols = data[0].length;

        for (int i = 0; i < numRows; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < numCols; j++) {
                if (j == col) {
                    s += data[i][j];
                    if (j < (numCols - 1)) s += " ";
                }
            }
        }

        return s;
    }
}
```